# Most efficient method to use position to open a .java

Tags: android

Sorry for the formating errors - How do you use position once you have it (or another variable for that matter) to activate a file or other task? For example I want to use position 1 to open screen1.java and position 2 to open screen2.java. I could use if/else statements but can I do it in one line rather than many? If I had 100 different screens then an if then statement would be silly. Here is what I have as an (incorrect) example. Can you help me correct it?

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
int position, long id){
//opens relevant game window
Intent intent = new Intent(context, "game"+(position)+"mainscreen"+".class");
startActivity(intent);
} 
});
}
```

TO SUMMARIZE:-
 **instead of using**  game1mainscreen.class  **I want to use something like**  "game"+(position)+"mainscreen"+".class"

Comment: So will you have 100 different classes!? If they are all somewhat similar, maybe you only need one that will act differently for each position parameter, sent in your intent's Bundle.

Comment: I actually have 4 different screens but was asking more of a general how to question. Thanks for your comment and suggestion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define intent filter for your activities in AndroidManifest.xml file as follows

```
<activity
  android:name=".Game1MainScreen"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.mygame.game1mainscreen" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and after that use following code to start your game activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.mygame.game"+(position)+"mainscreen");
startActivity(intent);
```