# Efficiently using position to control actions

Tags: java, android, position

I want to use position (returned from a gridview for e.g.) or a similar numeric integer to do various things, e.g. create a sprite, or in any command that wants something other than a number, e.g. I want to use something like:

```
sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.image(position));
```

, where createSprite creates a sprite using the image supplied,

instead of:

```
if (position == 1) {sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.image1);}
if (position == 2) {sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.image2);}
...etc
```

There is an easy solution for strings:

[Most efficient method to use position to open a .java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313315/most-efficient-method-to-use-position-to-open-a-java)

but what about for situations like this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disadvantage of the suggestion from @abhinav8, which definitely isn't a bad one by the way, is that you don't get the dynamic loading from different size/density buckets for free. Alternatively, you could just declare an array containing the resource ids and iterate through that.

A a last resort, I'd also like to point out a method that the `Resources` class provides:

[`getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

This allows you to dynamically look up a resource identifier by name, which means you could use it in a way similar to what is being suggested in the linked Q&A.

However, there's a catch, that is added as note in the method's documentation. It says:

> use of this function is **discouraged**. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.

That basically means: don't use it unless you really have to, and even then, use it scarcely. Just thought I should point out the method for completeness though.

Answer (score 1):

You can hold all the resource ids in an array. Then use the position as array index to retrieve the corresponding image resource id and load the image.

```
int resIDs[] = { R.drawwable.1, ...... };
```

then

```
sprites.add(createSprite(resIDs[position]);
```

Comment: I did this as a work around but I was hoping for something simpler.  : (

Comment: Why dint you use `getIdentifier` method as suggested in another answer...  But my method is faster.. you have take some pain to add every new resource id to the array.. but take it as an exercise..

Answer (score 0):

one way to do this is put all the images in `assest` folder and use `AssestsManager` to retrieve them.
like::

```
String imagePath =  "images/myimage"

InputStream is = getAssets().open( imagePath+position );        
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
sprites.add(createSprite(bmp)); ////modify your createsprite(),so that it can receive Bitmap
```

Comment: This might be good if I had a huge number but I am working with a dozen only at the moment. Thanks for the info though.